# When any function is applied to the output of any even function, is it odd or even? Explain

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I only need a couple of sentences to explain, but I don't know how to word it, please help!
I do not need an algebraic proof, just a sentence or two to explain why the output is always even.

Comment: Hint:  Look at the definition of an even function.  A real function is an even function iff for every $x$ you have that $f(x)=$_____  (*fill in the blank*).  Now... supposing that $f$ is an even function and $g$ is any other real function, notice that since $f$ is even you have that $(g\circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) = $______ (*fill in the blank*)... and it follows that _____.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be an even function and $g$ a real valued function such that $g \circ f$ is defined. We have that $g(f(-x)) = g(f(x))$, thus $g \circ f$ is even.